# CURL with PHP codeigniter: keep session on curl requests

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I've a basic web service written in Delphi. This web service is receiving POST requests with JSON via PHP Curl Library from [Phil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl) used on Codeigniter.

The server returns the data according to the request.

On the first request i send my authentication and i get the respective JSON.
On the second request the server identifies a different session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` so that cURL saves its cookies into a file.  The reason you are losing your session is because cURL is not persisting your session cookie across all of your requests.

So, for Code Igniter it would be something like this:

```
$this->curl->option(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'saved_cookies.txt');
```

Comment: also added this $this->curl->options(array(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath('tmp/cookie.txt') ) );